# How call controller after change select in asp.net core

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Select on my View, and im trying every time that i change select call my controller and pass selected value as parameter

```html
                            <form asp-controller="CompetitorsMarketplace" asp-action="Index" method="get" class="form-filters">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label">Markeplace</label>
                                            <select id="selectChangedValue" class="form-control" asp-for="MarketplaceName"
                                                    asp-items="Model.MarketplaceSelectList"></select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3 text-left ">

                                        <button class="btn btn-info btn-filter"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Filtrar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </form>
```

Controller

```
    public IActionResult Index(CompetitorByMarketPlaceViewModel competitorByMarketPlaceViewModel, string textSearchMarketplace, int page = 1)
    {

    }
```

and what i try via javascript

```html
    <script language="JavaScript">
    $('#selectChangedValue').on('change', function () {
        var postData = document.getElementById("selectChangedValue").value;
       // var post = { MarketplaceKey: postData};

        window.location = "/CompetitorsMarketplace/Index?textSearchMarketplace=" + postData;


    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Url.Action with Razor and fill your postdata with the .Replace jQuery function.

```
window.location = '@Url.Action("Index", "CompetitorsMarketplace", new { textSearchMarketplace = REPLACE })'.Replace('REPLACE',postData);
```